# Error in Deployment of Next.js App to Vercel

Tags: django-rest-framework, deployment, next.js, vercel, getstaticpaths

I have trying to Develop a Next.js App using Next.js and my Custom Backend with Django. I have completed it Developing everything which I have wanted to but When I'm trying to Deploy it to Vercel It gives me Error with getStaticPaths Every time I do that, However I tried to make the minimal Blog App I could using Next.js and the Dynamic Routing it is working fine without any problem.

Can you please help me in it as It's the final Step for the Development of my Blog App

The Error I Encounter =>

```
PS D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode> npm run build
 
> downthecode@0.1.0 build D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode
> next build && next export
 
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[==  ] info  - Generating static pages (0/16)
Error occurred prerendering page "/cateogary/[cateogary]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at cateogaryPageFun (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\.next\server\pages\cateogary\[cateogary].js:63:39)
    at d (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at exports.renderToString (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)        
    at Object.renderPage (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:854)
    at Function.getInitialProps (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\.next\server\pages\_document.js:603:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:1145)
 
Error occurred prerendering page "/hashtag/[hashtag]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at hashtagPageFun (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\.next\server\pages\hashtag\[hashtag].js:117:35)
    at d (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at exports.renderToString (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)        
    at Object.renderPage (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:854)
    at Function.getInitialProps (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\.next\server\pages\_document.js:603:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:1145)
[=== ] info  - Generating static pages (8/16)
Error occurred prerendering page "/posts/[post]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Headline' of undefined
    at index (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\.next\server\pages\posts\[post].js:745:32)
    at d (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at exports.renderToString (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)        
    at Object.renderPage (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:854)
    at Function.getInitialProps (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\.next\server\pages\_document.js:603:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\server\render.js:54:1145)
info  - Generating static pages (16/16)
 
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /cateogary/[cateogary]
        /hashtag/[hashtag]
        /posts/[post]
    at D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:31:1106
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584)
    at async D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:45:49
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584)
    at async D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:27:1475
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\Web Developement\Next Projects\BlogX\Down the Code\downthecode\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:6:584)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! downthecode@0.1.0 build: `next build && next export`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the downthecode@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\coder\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-25T09_16_55_757Z-debug.log
```

The Code of the Repo can be found here => `https://github.com/coderaman07/Days-of-Code`

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1):

Your `serverDomain` is always `serverDomain = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'`, because `domainName.isInDevelopement` always `"True"` (as a string type whihc does not make any to be fair).

So you are basically trying to fetch from localhost, but there is nothing there at Vercel localhost, python backend is not running there.

Comment: As for the Development I use to write that domainName.isInDevelopment  but for Deployment I use to remove that particular piece of line ( Currently It is in Development so I thought that there is no need to remove that line.